# LWC's APEX class not updating a Long text area field

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a LWC which has a text area that allows user to comment. My goal is to capture this comment in an Order record. Therefore, my LWC calls an apex method which then updates the a long text field in Order. Everything else in this survey is updating properly but this text area is not updating properly. I have no idea why. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="slds-m-top_large app-text-heading_xx-medium slds-text-align_center">
                Please rate this order experience.
            </div>
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
                <div class="slds-p-around_medium slds-grid slds-grid_align-center slds-grid_vertical-align-center">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-grow-none slds-shrink-none slds-p-right_x-small">Bad</div>
                    <template for:each={ratingValues} for:item="ratingValue">
                        <div key={ratingValue.rating} class="slds-col slds-grow-none slds-shrink-none">
                            <div class="star_wrap slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small slds-p-top_xx-small slds-p-bottom_xx-small">
                                <a data-rating={ratingValue.rating} onclick={onRating} class="starlink">
                                    <svg class={ratingValue.class} stroke="#2070bd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="255"
                                    height="240" viewBox="0 0 51 48">
                                    <path d="m25,1 6,17h18l-14,11 5,17-15-10-15,10 5-17-14-11h18z"></path>
                                </svg>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-grow-none slds-shrink-none slds-p-left_x-small">Good</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Star Rating of survey ends-->
            <!--Text area of Survey-->
            <div class="slds-m-top_large app-text-heading_xx-medium slds-text-align_center">
                Ideas or Feedback? Let us know.
            </div>
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
                <div class="slds-p-bottom_medium lgc-bg">
                    <lightning-textarea name="surveyText" label="Textarea field with a placeholder"
                        placeholder="Type your feedback here..." onchange={surveyResponseChange} value={surveyResponse}>
                    </lightning-textarea>
                </div>
                <lightning-button label="Send" onclick={getValues}> </lightning-button>
                <!--Send button for survey-->
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import createSurveyResponse from "@salesforce/apex/VirtualSellingCtrl.createSurveyResponse";

export default class mylWC extends NavigationMixin(
  LightningElement
) {
 @track selectedRatingValue = 0;
  @track surveyResponse;
onRating(e) {
    this.selectedRatingValue = parseInt(e.currentTarget.dataset.rating);
    this.ratingValues.forEach((rv) => {
      rv.class =
        rv.rating <= this.selectedRatingValue ? "star star_filled" : "star";
    });

    // ...
  }
// a different JS function is capturing the order id and then passing it to the createorder function
  surveyResponseChange(event){
      this.surveyResponse = event.target.value;
  }
  
  starClass(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.rating);
    return "star_wrap slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small slds-p-top_xx-small slds-p-bottom_xx-small";
  }
//Survey Response
  getValues(){
    createSurveyResponse({
      ordId: this.orderId,
      surveyStars: this.selectedRatingValue,
      surveyResponse: this.surveyResponse,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      
      this.resultValue = result;
      console.log(":surveyfeedback::this.resultValue::: " + this.resultValue);
      this.error = undefined;

      if (this.resultValue == "Thank you for your Survey Response") {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
          title: "",
          message: this.resultValue,
          variant: "success",
          mode: "dismissable",
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);

      }
      if (this.resultValue == "Error") {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
          title: "Error",
          message: "Server Problems",
          variant: "Error",
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.error = error;

      const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: "Error",
        message: this.error,
        variant: "Error",
      });
      this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    });
  }
```

APEX Class

```
@AuraEnabled
    global static string createSurveyResponse(String ordId, String surveyStars, String surveyResponse){
        System.debug('The order id in apex is ' + ordId);
        System.debug('The star rating apex is ' + surveyStars);
       if(surveyStars != '' || surveyResponse != ''){
        Order orderUpd = new Order(Id = ordId, Survey_Rating__c = surveyStars, Order_Survey_Response__c = surveyResponse); //the surveyrepsonse is not updating but the star rating is. Survey response is a long text area.
        update orderUpd; 

        return 'Thank you for your Survey Response';

       }else{
            return 'Error';
       }
    }
```

can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `lightning-textarea` is a base lwc. It uses javascript [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) to send details to its parent. The details are usually sent in CustomEvent optional [`detail`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/detail) property. So you need to change,

```
  this.surveyResponse = event.target.value;
```

to

```
  this.surveyResponse = event.detail.value;
```

And it should work fine.

Comment: thank you @sachin hooda